# He looks all about!

Tags: idioms

What does the phrase, "he looks all about" mean? Here is the context: He is shy, arrogant, and he looks all about. It must be a negative thing. Does it mean confused or distracted?

Comment: Normally I would think "he looks all about" means that he looks (with his eyes) in various directions.  That doesn't seem to make sense here.  Can you provide the full quotation?

Comment: I wouldn't say shy and arrogant go together in the description of a person. Anyway more context is needed. Possibly he is nervous and self-conscious, and looks everywhere to gain confidence.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered. After reading your helpful answers, I think it means he is not focused on one thing, but rather moves from one job to another without accomplishing anything. It is figurative.

Answer (score 1):

It likely means that he looks around his environment a lot. For example, if he is in a workplace, he would be quiet, come off as arrogant to others even if he's not really that way on purpose. And that he looks around the workplace a lot at other people and things. As to why he looks around a lot, only he could answer that. Maybe it's because he's nervous that people are talking about him, or just curious to see what other people are doing, or maybe he's just daydreaming and not really focusing on where it appears he's looking.